# Passing values in button instead of href link

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts

I have a href link which passes some values to the action class in Struts 2.

```jsp
<a href='<s:url action='generatePdf' escapeAmp="false">
<s:param name='selectedValue' value='selectedValue' />
<s:param name='fromTransactionDate' value='fromTransactionDate' />
<s:param name='fromDate' value='fromDate' />
</s:url>'>
    <font   style="color: blue;">Generate PDF</font>
</a>
```

I want to use a button instead of the link. Not able to find the way for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```jsp
<s:url var="myUrl" action='generatePdf' escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name='selectedValue' value='selectedValue' />
    <s:param name='fromTransactionDate' value='fromTransactionDate' />
    <s:param name='fromDate' value='fromDate' />
</s:url>
<input type="button" style="color: blue;" value="Generate PDF"
       onclick="window.location='<s:property value="%{#myUrl}"/>';">
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to just use an image instead of text

```
<a href='<s:url action='generatePdf' escapeAmp="false">
  <s:param name='selectedValue' value='selectedValue' />
  <s:param name='fromTransactionDate' value='fromTransactionDate' />
  <s:param name='fromDate' value='fromDate' />
  </s:url>'>
  <img src="myimage.jpg">
</a>
```

If you want the button to have a "buttony" feel to it when you hover over it and when you click on it, you need to go a bit further.